# Deleting rows from a tab delimited text file that contain a certain number in a string

Tags: awk, sed

So I have data that looks like this

```
chr1    169845117   169845232   -   ENSG00000000457.9_exNb11
chr1    169847773   169847960   -   ENSG00000000457.9_exNb12
chr1    169771760   169771866   +   ENSG00000000460.12_exNb4
chr1    169772308   169772450   +   ENSG00000000460.12_exNb5
chr6    41046766    41046903    +   ENSG00000001167.10_exNb2
chr6    41051783    41051931    +   ENSG00000001167.10_exNb4
chr6    41057316    41057449    +   ENSG00000001167.10_exNb5
chr6    41057941    41058048    +   ENSG00000001167.10_exNb6
chr6    41059265    41059433    +   ENSG00000001167.10_exNb7
chr6    41060649    41060824    +   ENSG00000001167.10_exNb8
chr6    41062133    41062236    +   ENSG00000001167.10_exNb9
chr6    46097728    46097926    +   ENSG00000001561.6_exNb1
```

I would like to remove rows that have a 1 at the end of the exNb string in the 5th column such as the last row in the above. There is probably an awk or sed option that would let me do this, but as I have zero experience in either language i'm hoping someone can help me out, i'm not sure how complicated this is.

EDIT: The desired result is the following

```
chr1    169845117   169845232   -   ENSG00000000457.9_exNb11
chr1    169847773   169847960   -   ENSG00000000457.9_exNb12
chr1    169771760   169771866   +   ENSG00000000460.12_exNb4
chr1    169772308   169772450   +   ENSG00000000460.12_exNb5
chr6    41046766    41046903    +   ENSG00000001167.10_exNb2
chr6    41051783    41051931    +   ENSG00000001167.10_exNb4
chr6    41057316    41057449    +   ENSG00000001167.10_exNb5
chr6    41057941    41058048    +   ENSG00000001167.10_exNb6
chr6    41059265    41059433    +   ENSG00000001167.10_exNb7
chr6    41060649    41060824    +   ENSG00000001167.10_exNb8
chr6    41062133    41062236    +   ENSG00000001167.10_exNb9
```

Comment: Edited that in for you. Essentially the only thing that changes is that the last row is removed because it has a 1. Incase you have a biological background, I am simply trying to remove all the first exons from my analysis.

Comment: all you need is `grep -v 'exNb1$' filename` to exclude those lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F\\t '$5 ~ /1$/ {next} {print}'
```

If there might be trailing blanks, then you will probably want to robustify the above by using `/1 *$/` as the regex.  If your file is really as simple as you describe, then you could just use `grep -v '1$'` (or `grep -v '1 *$'`), etc etc.

Of course, if the criterion is based on the numeric value of all the trailing numeric digits, then you'd have to made adjustments. (In that case, you'd have to think about "01", "1E0", "1.0", "0.1e1", etc.)

Comment: This looks like it solved it, thank you very much! Will accept this as the answer as soon as i'm allowed.

Comment: Or simply `awk '!/1$/'`. Note that *tab* is one of the default delimiters. Further we can simply match the whole line since we are checking the last column.

Comment: Won't this also remove lines ending with `exNb11`, `exNb21`, etc., as well?

Comment: Oh yes I see. But your awk solution is doing that too. (I've just looked at your answer, not at the question). It should be `grep -v '[^[:digit:]]1$'` then